# Webpack change properties to devServer

Tags: javascript, vue.js, webpack, webpack-dev-server

i'm trying to use a plugin in my vuejs project that allows me to create projects in VUE within CMS October, however i updated my node and i believe i updated the webpack version too (from what i've researched) and now my plugin is not working for that error is occurring right on that line of code.

The properties of disableHostCheck and public no longer exist, I would like to know which one I could replace that would have the same effect?

I've been searching the webpack documentation and I couldn't understand which one would be equivalent.

```
// configure the dev server and public path based on environment
    options.devServer = {
        disableHostCheck: true,
        public: 'http://localhost:8080',
    };
```

```
ValidationError: Invalid options object. Dev Server has been initialized using an options object that does not match the API schema.
         - options has an unknown property 'public'. These properties are valid:
           object { allowedHosts?, bonjour?, client?, compress?, devMiddleware?, headers?, historyApiFallback?, host?, hot?, http2?, https?, ipc?, liveReload?, magicHtml?, onAfterSetupMiddleware?, onBeforeSetupMiddleware?, onListening?, open?, port?, proxy?, server?, setupExitSignals?, setupMiddlewares?, static?, watchFiles?, webSocketServer? }
```

Answer (score 2):

In webpack 5 is changed, please check:

```
 devServer: {
    allowedHosts: 'all',
 }
```